# Finding Inverse After LU Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
60 & 30 & 20 \\
30 & 20 & 15 \\
20 & 15 & 15
\end{pmatrix}$$

a. Find LU Decomposition

b. Use a to find $A^{-1}$

So I found:

$$L=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0.5 & 1 & 0 \\
0.3333 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, U=\begin{pmatrix}
60 & 30 & 20 \\
0 & 5 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 3.3334
\end{pmatrix}$$

As for $b$ I need to find $A^{-1}=U^{-1}L^{-1}$?
Is there a shorter way as $L$ and $U$ are triangular matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the inverses of triangular matrices is easier, indeed, because the inverse is triangular again. In particular, if the size is small, you can pretty much do it in your head. For example, for $U$, we must have
$$\begin{pmatrix} 60 & 30 & 20 \\ 0 & 5 & 5 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{10}{3} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ 0 & d & e \\ 0 & 0 & f \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
For the first entry, this yields $60a = 1$, hence $a = \frac{1}{60}$. Similarly, $d = \frac{1}{5}$ and $f = \frac{3}{10}$. Next, $60b + 30d = 0$, hence $b = -\frac{1}{10}$ and so on. I am sure you can finish this and do the same for $L$, too.